# How to use sum with 2 different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, i got 2 tables

And i want to get sum of each tables, since one column is number and the second column is %.
Is that right query?

```
SELECT pp.agr_id, sum(pp.p_sum),sum(pi.p_sum) FROM payments_principal pp
   INNER JOIN payments_interest pi
   ON pp.agr_id = pi.agr_id 
   GROUP BY pp.agr_id, pi.agr_id
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: And what results do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff agr_id, sum of payments_principal, and sum of payments_interest . Like 31 - 44546 - 88%

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the totals from both tables, then you would need `full join`.  But MySQL does not support that.  So:

```
SELECT agr_id, sum(pp_sum),sum(pi_sum)
FROM ((SELECT pp.agr_id, p_sum as pp_sum, 0 as pi_sum
       FROM payments_principal pp
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT pi.agr_id, 0 as pp_sum, p_sum as pi_sum
       FROM payments_interest pi
      )
     ) pip
GROUP BY agr_id;
```

Comment: thank you, sir! Also is that correct way to sum % in SQL? By using SUM function?

Comment: also sir what if i only want agr_id which has in two tables (inner join) is there any way to solve it? Like to select  agr_id which presents  in both tables